# Trying to creare ticketing app using freshdesk APi but throwing Error 401 and unauthorized message

Tags: javascript, ajax, postman, freshdesk

I'm creating the ticket app using JS, for api integration I'm using freshdesk api and doing create ticket feature, but its showing error 401: unauthorized like below image,

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6bgo7.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8mn4n.png)

Can someone help me on this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you actually need is the API key from Freshdesk to make the requests. First of all, you will need to create a Freshdesk account, and in your profile, you will find your API key or you will need to generate it there.

Go through the [Freshdesk's](https://developers.freshdesk.com/api/#authentication)
documentation. Hope this will help you. You know most of today's APIs require some kind of authentication and if you don't provide API keys, you will get 401 (Unauthorized) rejection from the server.